# Parse a string (in UTC+ format) to date format in either C# or javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

How to parse a string (in UTC+ format) to date in either C# or javascript?

Brief background of the issue -

While reading an excel file at client side (javascript), the date value is retrieved in 'Sun Dec 12 06:00:00 UTC+0530 2010' format. Once data has been read from the excel file, it is passed on to the server side (C#). For further processing, this date in string format needs to be parsed in date format.

I am thinking of the best possible way to address this. So formatting either in client-side or server-side is an open option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side you could use DateTime.ParseExact() to parse the date time format into an actual DateTime object.  For example the following code will work with the example Date value:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Dec 12 06:00:00 UTC+0530 2010", 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", 
    null);
```

Comment: You should add a CultureInfo object as a parameter to ParseExact. 'Sun' for instance is only valid for an english culture.

Comment: Won't `zzz` expect `+05:30` and not `+0530`?

Comment: Thanks Adam!!.. Worked for me.. Steven.. I understand your point.. We should use cultureinfo... Thanks to both of you..

Answer (score 2):

```
 // will work
 var d = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Dec 12 06:00:00 UTC+0530 2010", 
      "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", 
      new CultureInfo("en"));

 // will throw a FomatException
 var e = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Dec 12 06:00:00 UTC+0530 2010", 
      "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", 
      new CultureInfo("fr"));
```

Note that the returned DateTime object won't be in UTC time.

Comment: Format exception occurs when the date is like `"Mon Aug 5 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013"`. Here the date is 1 digit `5` and the format should be like `"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy"`

Answer (score 0):

in .NET you can probably use the DateTime.Parse(String) method : [DateTime Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Comment: Jas.. Parse method would give "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.", if you directly use the string in this format... This parse method accept string format of following..   
t ShortTimePattern h:mm tt 
d ShortDatePattern M/d/yyyy 
T LongTimePattern h:mm:ss tt 
D LongDatePattern dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy 
f (combination of D and t) dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt 
F FullDateTimePattern dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt 
g (combination of d and t) M/d/yyyy h:mm tt 
G (combination of d and T) M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt

Comment: m, M MonthDayPattern MMMM dd 
y, Y YearMonthPattern MMMM, yyyy 
r, R RFC1123Pattern ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (*) 
s SortableDateTi­mePattern yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss (*) 
u UniversalSorta­bleDateTimePat­tern yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' (*) 
    (*) = culture independent